# Sagemaker to use processed pickled ndarray instead of csv files from S3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-sagemaker

I understand that you can pass a CSV file from S3 into a Sagemaker XGBoost container using the following code

```py
train_channel = sagemaker.session.s3_input(train_data, content_type='text/csv')
valid_channel = sagemaker.session.s3_input(validation_data, content_type='text/csv')

data_channels = {'train': train_channel, 'validation': valid_channel}
xgb_model.fit(inputs=data_channels,  logs=True)
```

But I have an ndArray stored in S3 bucket. These are processed, label encoded, feature engineered arrays. I would want to pass this into the container instead of the csv. I do understand I can always convert my ndarray into csv files before saving it in S3. Just checking if there is an array option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple options for algorithms in SageMaker:

1. [Built-in algorithms](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/algos.html), like the SageMaker XGBoost you mention
2. Custom, user-created algorithm code, which can be:

   - Written for a pre-built docker image, available for Sklearn, TensorFlow, Pytorch, MXNet
   - Written in your own container

When you use built-ins (option 1), your choice of data format options is limited to what the built-ins support, [which is only csv and libsvm in the case of the built-in XGBoost](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/xgboost.html#InputOutput-XGBoost). If you want to use custom data formats and pre-processing logic before XGBoost, it is absolutely possible if you use your own script leveraging the open-source XGBoost. You can get inspiration from the [Random Forest demo](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/master/sagemaker-python-sdk/scikit_learn_randomforest/Sklearn_on_SageMaker_end2end.ipynb) to see how to create custom models in pre-built containers